# git config --list infinte struck

Tags: git, github

I am new to git. As tutorials shows->    "git config --list"   shows up the user name and email and other information, is not happening with me. Instead of that my screen produces following output in my terminal

```
core.legacyheaders=false
core.quotepath=false
mergetool.keepbackup=true
push.default=simple
color.ui=auto
color.interactive=auto
repack.usedeltabaseoffset=true
alias.s=status
alias.a=!git add . && git status
alias.au=!git add -u . && git status
alias.aa=!git add . && git add -u . && git status
alias.c=commit
alias.cm=commit -m
alias.ca=commit --amend
alias.ac=!git add . && git commit
alias.acm=!git add . && git commit -m
alias.l=log --graph --all --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset %s %C(white)- %an, %ar%Creset'
alias.ll=log --stat --abbrev-commit
alias.lg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%h%Creset -%C(bold green)%d%Creset %s %C(bold green)(%cr)%Creset %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
alias.llg=log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%C(bold white)%H %d%Creset%n%s%n%+b%C(bold blue)%an <%ae>%Creset %C(bold green)%cr (%ci)' --abbrev-commit
alias.d=diff
alias.master=checkout master
alias.spull=svn rebase
alias.spush=svn dcommit
alias.alias=!git config --list | grep 'alias\.' | sed 's/alias\.\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\1\     => \2/' | sort
include.path=~/.gitcinclude
include.path=.githubconfig
include.path=.gitcredential
diff.exif.textconv=exif
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.name=Amandeep
user.email=amandeep.verma@live.in
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
:
```

At this point of time I have to press control+z to get out of it. Any direction of help please.

Comment: The last ":" indicates you are using a pager. Try pressing "q" to quit the pager. You don't have to press control+z. And you can press arrow keys to scroll up and down. If you don't want a pager, try `git --no-pager config --list`.

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay, it make sense to me now and `git --no-pager config --list` worked smooth.
Arrow keys seems not to work. Can you provide a bit insight on what difference does it make when i use pager and when i don't use it.

Comment: Imagine that the console screen is a page. If the output is short, one page is enough to show all the content. If it's lengthy, you will see only the last page. The upper parts are hidden and you'll have to scroll up to read them. It would be quite inconvenient if the output has dozens of pages. A pager like `more` and `less` makes the output a book. The first page is displayed at first and then you can scroll up and down by line or by page or jump to a certain keyword. See https://debian-administration.org/article/246/An_overview_of_file_paging_applications for more.